# Getting errors when trying to install socket.io globally

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

I am new to node, npm, socket.io. Found many guides that are fairly useful, but I am encountering some errors which I don't understand the cause, hopefully you can help me out.

```
npm install socket.io -g
```

returns ...

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm ERR! error installing socket.io@0.9.4
npm ERR! error rolling back socket.io@0.9.4 Error: EACCES, unlink   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/.npmignore'
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/.npmignore'
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Kinglee
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/.npmignore
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! message EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/.npmignore'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Kinglee/npm-debug.log
```

however when i did `npm install socket.io`, there was no error, everything was fine.

Sorry forget to add this info here ...

I actually tried `sudo npm install socket.io` and it installed without error but when i try to `cd ~/node_modules`, I don't see socket.io, this cause `'socket.io not found' error` when i try to do `require('socket.io')` as I follow this tutorial here (http://blog.koostudios.com/?p=470)

Kind of confused fellow here :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most important portion is:

```
EACCES, unlink   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/.npmignore'
```

This means you do not have permission to delete this file.

I assume this means you ran the command as your standard user account, which will not have write permission into `/usr/`.

Prepend `sudo` to your command to re-run the command with administrator privileges:

```
sudo npm install socket.io -g
```

Your local configuration may not have `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` in `node`'s default module loading locations. The module loading path is controlled via the `NODE_PATH` environment variable (before starting `node`) or the `require.paths` variable (once `node` is running). Because I prefer to keep local configuration separated from the program, I'd prefer to set the environment variable to modify paths, though the other mechanism may be useful for long-lived applications that must remain up even when the environment changes. (This is definitely an advanced use.)

To change the `NODE_PATH` variable for a single instance, `sh` and its derivatives will let you simply add `NODE_PATH=/path` before the command. For example, change:

```
node ./foo.js
```

to

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules ./foo.js
```

If you have multiple directories, use the standard `:`-separated directories, just as you would for `PATH`:

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/home/sarnold/node_modules ./foo.js
```

To make this persistent, use the shell's `export` builtin to export the value of the `NODE_PATH` variable to all children *and* place the modification in your shell's start up files, such as `~/.bashrc`:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

This will take effect in all new shells automatically. You can `source` this file into currently-running shells if you don't wish to restart them:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Oh ya, I forget to add that I actually tried 'sudo npm install socket.io -g' and it installed well. But when I cd to ~/node_modules, I don't see socket.io. This causes error 'socket.io not found' when i try to do 'node main.js' on a tutorial i was following (http://blog.koostudios.com/?p=470).

Comment: You may need to add `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` to the `NODE_PATH` environment variable before starting `node`, or modify `require.paths` within your script. I'd prefer the environment variable, as it doesn't hardcode system environment knowledge into the program. Try running: `NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules node foo.js` -- tha is, prepend the `NODE_PATH` assignment before the `node` command. If that works, then add `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to your `~/.bashrc` file. (And report back; I'll clean up the answer and comments...)

Comment: Ok here is what i did ...
npm rm socket.io, 
node main.js // return Cannot find module 'socket.io' which is right,
sudo npm install socket.io -g // Everything went fine,
..checking if socket.io is in ~/node_modules.. // no it's not,
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules node main.js // Ooo, it works,
.. added path to .bash_profile,
node main.js // sweet it works. Thanks alot.,

Argh I am getting 'io is not defined error' in the console, on this line "socket = io.connect 'http://localhost'", i suspect the url is wrong for my setup.. hmm

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here, as it helped me with a similar problem:
[NPM no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633029/npm-no-longer-working)

Had some good answers. 
Hope it helps.