# Can't get Socket.IO to install on Ubuntu VPS server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, socket.io

I am having trouble to get socket.io installed in the correct directory I guess for it to work with my website. I had it working at one point, however I had to install socketIO in the directory with my website files (so that was cluttered and couldn't be there, i deleted those files and now it no longer works).

My website files are located in: `/var/www/`

Node.js seems to work fine globally as when I type, `node -v` anywhere it gives me the version.

I have tried `sudo npm install socket.io -g` but that didn't fix the issue. Where am I suppose to install socket.io, or how am I suppose to in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate:
[Getting errors when trying to install socket.io globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968442/getting-errors-when-trying-to-install-socket-io-globally)

You have to install npm packages in the project folder where your package.json and node_modules folder exist if doing locally. For global installation you must have NODE_PATH variable containing your global package folder, which should be /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Comment: Thanks, I tried going through that person's answer however I was unable to get it to work. It just kept saying that I didn't have permission to do it (I was using my root account so that shouldn't have been an issue). But I may not have been doing it correctly.