# NPM no longer working

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, npm, jasmine

so I wasn't paying attention and ran this command-

```
npm install npm install jasmine-node -g
```

which caused this -

```
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/install/-/install-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/install/-/install-0.1.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node/-/jasmine-node-1.4.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node/-/jasmine-node-1.4.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.2.15.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.2.15.tgz
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/install'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/install']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/install',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/install',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ 'DirWriter._create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23)',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "npm" "install" "jasmine-node" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/psanker/Google Drive/Coding/Javascript/WhatsGoingOn
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/install
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/install
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/install'
npm ERR! fstream_stack DirWriter._create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23)
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ 'DirWriter._create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23)',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "npm" "install" "jasmine-node" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/psanker/Google Drive/Coding/Javascript/WhatsGoingOn
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node'
npm ERR! fstream_stack DirWriter._create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23)
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back  npm@1.2.15 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "npm" "install" "jasmine-node" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/psanker/Google Drive/Coding/Javascript/WhatsGoingOn
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/psanker/Google Drive/Coding/Javascript/WhatsGoingOn/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Now when I try and run

```
npm install jasmine-node -g
```

I get

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

What's going on?

Comment: how did you install node on your machine ?

Comment: I recommend against installing npm packages as root/administrator. See here for an alternative way: https://coderwall.com/p/6aumug/howto-npm-global-install-without-root-privileges

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Tried it myself.

You will need to install `npm` again. If you use `git`, this is the easiest way:

```
git clone http://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install
```

Otherwise, there is an install script too:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

(possibly you will need to use `sudo sh` instead of `sh`).

Then install your module again:

```
sudo npm install jasmine-node -g
```

**EDIT 23/01/2014:**

Now npm comes with NodeJs itself, so just reinstall [NodeJs](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: Ahh yes, as my unixfoo is weak, i have been doing `sudo curl://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh` which has been erroring out.  I did not realize that piping required another layer of `sudo`!  Thanks

Comment: @Michael Fell into that pitfall myself too ;)

Comment: Should be curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh now https://github.com/npm/npm#fancy-install-unix

Answer (score 115):

When you run npm install -g somepackage, you may get an EACCES error asking you to run the command again as root/Administrator. It's a permissions issue.

It's **easy to fix**, open your terminal (Applications > Utilities > Terminal)

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

** I strongly recommend you to not use the package management with sudo (sudo npm -g install something), because you can get some issues later **

Reference: http://foohack.com/2010/08/intro-to-npm/

**** Update ****

The reason is because this can cause permissions problems with lots of other apps, so I'd suggest not doing this.

**A better solution when you are installing globally:**

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

Comment: I understand the usage of separate user being beneficial against root access. Still i would not recommend doing "sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local".
As here what you are trying to do is permitting everything in /usr/local to the $USER. I would not want that specific $USER to have all the permissions.

The solution should just be finding the exact folder in /usr/local or whichever location and giving that only the right to be used by $USER. This too is drastically vulnerable to misuse.

Another solution that i prefer is to "chmod" the exact package with SOME EXTRA permissions for separate users.

Comment: I did this command, but qualifying it down to just the node_modules directory.  /usr/local/lib/node_modules and it worked beautifully.

Comment: @pruett you can install node using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814)

Comment: worked for me, as root: `chown -R jenkins /opt/node` and `chgrp -R jenkins /opt/node`

Answer (score 10):

Look at the error

```
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

You need to run this with `sudo`

```
$ sudo npm install jasmine-node -g
```

Comment: @praks5432 `sudo` not found? well, I'm sorry but that's all the help I can give you... I have no idea what to do in that case.

Comment: This hint helped me in a Windows env install. The install was stuck in the second "GET" command, without any error message...

Comment: @romainberger it's not a good idea to use npm as root, that will cause you problems later

Comment: The not found error is due to npm being available only to your user and not to root. Do what the highest rated answer says and just fix your permissions `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` - super simple.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me (OSX). I had to run it in my user directory.

`cd ~`

`curl -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the permissions issues by setting my packages to install locally with a one-line "$HOME/.npmrc" file:

prefix=${HOME}/.npm_packages